# Issue in string matching

Tags: string, c#-4.0

I am using this code:

```
 string[] spl = { };
 if (theLine.Contains("Value of perquisites u/s 17(2)"))
 spl = new string[] { "17(2)" };
 else if (theLine.Contains("Value of perquisites under section 17(2) (as per"))
 spl = new string[] { "(as per" };
 else if (theLine.Contains("Value of perquisites under section 17(2) (as per Form"))
 spl = new string[] { "Form" };
 else if (theLine.Contains("Value of perquisites u/s 17(2) (as per Form No.12BA,"))
 spl = new string[] { "12BA," };
 else if (theLine.Contains("Value of perquisites under section 17(2) (as per Form No.      12BA, wherever"))
 spl = new string[] { "wherever" };
```

when i am searching for last condition then it will match the first condition. Plz Help Thanx in advance.

Comment: So place the last condition before the first

Comment: if i search for third condition then it will meet to first according to your answer

Comment: Just put the first condition as the last condition then. When you say that, youre actually saying your answer too

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the conditions, so that you match the longer strings first:

```
string[] spl = { };
if (theLine.Contains("Value of perquisites under section 17(2) (as per Form No.      12BA, wherever"))
  spl = new string[] { "wherever" }
else if (theLine.Contains("Value of perquisites u/s 17(2) (as per Form No.12BA,"))
  spl = new string[] { "12BA," };
else if (theLine.Contains("Value of perquisites u/s 17(2)"))
  spl = new string[] { "17(2)" };
else if (theLine.Contains("Value of perquisites under section 17(2) (as per Form"))
  spl = new string[] { "Form" };
else if (theLine.Contains("Value of perquisites under section 17(2) (as per"))
  spl = new string[] { "(as per" };
```

This will also make the (previously) third and fourth options avaiable.